How to connect to libvirt guest sshd over SLIRP?
When invoking virt-install with --network user the result is a VM (or domain in libvirt parlance) that is created in the default hypervisor, i.e. in qemu:///session with SLIRP networking configured.
But how do I actually connect to the sshd running inside that new guest?
The virt-install man pages states:

user [:] Connect to the LAN using SLIRP. Only use this if running a QEMU guest as an unprivileged  user.  This  provides a very limited form of NAT.

And some networking on the guest side seems to have been created:
$ virsh domifaddr myvm --source agent
 Name       MAC address          Protocol     Address
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 lo         00:00:00:00:00:00    ipv4         127.0.0.1/8
 -          -                    ipv6         ::1/128
 enp1s0     52:54:00:e4:08:1b    ipv4         10.0.2.15/24
[..]

But how am I suppose to actually ssh from the Fedora host into the guest?
Do I need to set up some extra port forwarding with virsh?

FWIW, custom user style unprivileged networking with plain qemu does work on this machine, however, I'm kind of expecting libvirt to come up with some sane defaults and a complete setup when using --network user. For example by choosing a free port from a range for me and offering some kind of introspection to learn what host-port is forwarded.
Also, when invoking virt-install against the system virtd, i.e. with --connect qemu://system --network default ..., the domifaddr virsh command works out of the box, and I can ssh connect to the reported IP address without further ado.
